# subset R data frame using only exact matches of character vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I would like to subset a data frame *(Data)* by column names. I have a character vector with column name IDs I want to exclude *(IDnames)*.

What I do normally is something like this:

```
Data[ ,!colnames(Data) %in% IDnames]
```

However, I am facing the problem that there is a name "X-360" and another one "X-360.1" in the columns. I only want to exclude the "X-360" (which is also in the character vector), but not "X-360.1" (which is not in the character vector, but extracted anyway). - So I want only exact matches, and it seems like this does not work with %in%.

It seems such a simple problem but I just cannot find a solution...

**Update**:

Indeed, the problem was that I had duplicated names in my data.frame! It took me a while to figure this out, because when I looked at the subsetted columns with

```
Data[ ,colnames(Data) %in% IDnames]
```

it showed "X-360" and "X-360.1" among the names, as stated above.
But it seems this was just happening when subsetting the data, before there were just columns with the *same* name ("X-360") - and that happened because the data frame was set up from matrices with cbind.
Here is a demonstration of what happened:

```
D1 <-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)
colnames(D1) <- c("X-360", "X-400", "X-401", "X-300", "X-302", "X-500")

D2 <-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)
colnames(D2) <- c("X-360", "X-406", "X-403", "X-300", "X-305", "X-501")

D <- cbind(D1, D2)
Data <- as.data.frame(D)

IDnames <- c("X-360", "X-302", "X-501")

Data[ ,colnames(Data) %in% IDnames]
       X-360      X-302    X-360.1      X-501
1 -0.3658194 -1.7046575  2.1009329  0.8167357
2 -2.1987411 -1.3783129  1.5473554 -1.7639961
3  0.5548391  0.4022660 -1.2204003 -1.9454138
4  0.4010191 -2.1751914  0.8479660  0.2800923
5 -0.2790987  0.1859162  0.8349893  0.5285602
6  0.3189967  1.5910424  0.8438429  0.1142751
```

Learned another thing to be careful about when working with such data in the future...

Comment: Ok I checked it now again with random data and you're right, I am receiving what I want and what you expected... But not with my original data. Could it be that this is because I get this data by cbind from two data frames where some IDs are the same and then they are automatically renamed to preserve identical names? It must be related to this...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You are right, I updated it above.

Answer (score 1):

One regex based solution here would be to form an alternation of exact keyword matches:

```
regex <- paste0("^(?:", paste(IDnames, collapse="|"), ")$")
Data[ , !grepl(regex, colnames(Data))]
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer! I tried this out, but unfortunately I still have the same problem... This ID "X-360.1" was again extracted...

Comment: ... that can't happen with my code.  If you search for column name `X-360`, then the above script will match that name _exactly_, and that name only.  You might not be using my code, I think.